# How to change the language in CKEDITOR 5

Tags: ckeditor

I tried to change the language in CKEDITOR 5, I did everything as advised but the language didn't change.

This was the code I put there:

script src='https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/41.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js'

script src='https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/41.1.0/classic/translations/sv.js'

[Here is a picture of those two lines I added into the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMmA7.png)

and here is the web page where I found the instructions:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.